# Creating line with multiple points with Python in QGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I have a multiple set of coordinates (about 100 points or more, I get it by function). I need to create a new layer with line from this points. Could somebody explain how to do it, please? The part of my code in here. I'm new in PyQGIS.
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340705/creating-line-layer-with-features-using-pyqgis - check this answer